# How to compute Final Grade with assignment weightings?

Tags: analysis, arithmetic, education, average, percentages

I have just finished the Final for my Computer Hardware course, and I'm trying to figure out where my grade currently stands. The way the class is broken up is 50% weight for the homework, 25% for the Midterm, and 25% for the Final.

Looking at things straight forward, there are 14 graded entries for 100 points each.

```
Assignment                            Possible Points    Score      Grade
Hw 1 - 1.13-15, 2.15, 2.19            100.00             100.00     A
Lab 1 - 7-SEGMENT Display             100.00             100.00     A
Hw 2 - 3.24, 29, 4.3, 7, 32           100.00              90.00     A
Lab 2 - 8 * 8 Memory Register         100.00             100.00     A
Midterm                               100.00              79.00     C
Hw 3 - 5.5, 11, 23, Marie 4.3, 14     100.00             100.00     A
Lab 3 - Build an Alu                  100.00             100.00     A
Hw 5 - 8.1, 8, 12, 15, 22             100.00             100.00     A
Lab 5 - Build Cpu Use Alu From Lab3   100.00              75.00     C
Hw 6 - 10.14, 11.6, 12.8, 13.9, 14.2  100.00             100.00     A
Lab 6 - Memory Unit & Bus on Cpu      100.00               0.00
Hw 7 - 1+ Questions for Review        100.00             100.00     A
Lab 7 - Test Program for Pc           100.00               0.00
Final                                 100.00               ?.??
```

As things stand without the Final, I'm showing (according to the online grade book) 79.95%. I feel like the final went good, but I'm not sure how to Account for the weightings of 50% for homework, 25% Midterm, 25% Final.

I'm trying to figure out how to compute, if say, the grade on my final was a 79% just like on my Midterm.

Can anyone show me the proper methodology here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homework + lab total:  $$1 + 1 + .9 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + .75 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 = 9.65$$  Homework + lab average: $$9.65/14 = 0.689286.$$  I have assumed that there are 7 homework and lab assignments each, and that the missing value for Homework 4 and Lab 4 are zero.  If that is not the case, adjust the values accordingly.

Midterm = 0.79.  Suppose the final is $x$, where $0 \le x \le 1$.  Then the final grade is $$0.689286 \cdot 0.50 + 0.79 \cdot 0.25 + 0.25 x.$$  The minimum $x$ required to get a score of $0.8$, a B, is over 100%, meaning it is not possible to get anything higher than a C.  If, however, there was no Assignment 4, then the calculation would be $x = 0.8016$, meaning you would need just over 80% on the final to get a B.  Even under this assumption, there is no possibility of getting an A.

From the information you provided that your grade so far is 79.95%, it appears that there was no Homework/Lab 4.  That calculation presumes that there is no final, and that the homework + labs are worth twice the midterm.  To get the overall score from this, you would simply renormalize:  $$0.7995 \cdot 0.75 + 0.25 x$$ is your overall score if $x$ is the score on your final.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought-out answer heropup! There was indeed no HW#4 (that week was a pass on HW due to the Midterm, same with no HW#8 for week 8 and the Final). I'm more than happy with a 'C', but was trying to tell if a 'B' was truly attainable (been a tough course!) The Final I listed as `?.??` as the grade is unknown, but to be computed. As for the homework, every homework assignment has until Friday at midnight to be turned in for credit, meaning some of those zero's are <100 grades could be increased. I'm just trying to figure out how close (if possible) I am to a Final grade of [B].

Comment: My own workings came out to: `(9.65 / 12 = 0.8041666 * 0.50 = 0.40208) + (0.79 * 0.25 = 0.1975) + (0.25x)` = `0.59958 + 0.25x`. So for a [B] a grade of 78/79 is needed on the Final (if rounding up) or to be certain an 80 `(0.59958 + 0.20 = 0.79958)`. It'll be close, but not sure if I got the 80 on the Final personally. If my Math is right, if I got even over a 40% on the Final `(0.4*0.25 = 0.1 + 0.59958 = 0.69958)`, then a [C] (minimum passing grade) is guaranteed. I'll turn in something at least partial for those missing assignments and see if I can't boost a few points for the [B]. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume homework includes labs.  Let $x$ be your score on the final.

Weighted average = $.25\cdot\frac{965}{1200}+.25\cdot\frac{79}{100}+.50\cdot\frac{x}{100}=.3985+\frac{x}{200}$.

If you score $79$ on the final, your average would be $.3985+\frac{79}{200}=.7935$.  Your percentage would be $79.35\%$

Answer (score 0):

Take the sum of the weight*score, divide by sum of weight.

In your case, you should also apply a new weight for homework: with 12 assignments, and the total weigth = 25%, the weight for each assignment is 25%/12.